# Can't see uploaded files in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am uploading some Excel files into Azure blob storage(Data Lake Storage Gen2 enabled) manually. After uploading the file, I can see the uploaded status in the notification window, But I could not see that file in the corresponding folder. Tried with the different files, but the same issue. It was working fine till morning today.
File size: ~150Kb

Any idea?

Comment: what's the region of your storage account?

Comment: West US, East US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there're some changes in progress for azure portal -> blob storage and Gen2.

Last week, I had the same issue. But now it's completely ok for me. And currently, this issue is still there for some of my colleagues.

As a workaround, when uploading the file, you can specify the path by expanding the `Advanced` -> then specify the path in "upload to folder":

[image]

Comment: Thank you. After mentioning the path, the files were uploaded to the mentioned folder and I can see the files now. Files uploaded to the root folder If we don't mention the path.